# Issue implementing a Rotation Tween Animation in Android

Tags: android, android-animation

Following is my rotate_center.xml file for Animation

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rotate
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="350"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:duration="2000" />
```

What I try to do in my .class

```
tweenAnimation = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgTweenAnimation);

Animation animationRotateCenter= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotate_center);

tweenAnimation.startAnimation(animationRotateCenter);

while(count < animationRotateCenter.getDuration())
{
    count++;

    if(count == 4000)
    {
        Log.i(getPackageName(), getLocationClassName() + ": " + count);
        break;
    }
}

//Move to next Intent
```

The thing is, I executes fine, but does not show the animation. the logic runs fine in background until it is executed and then it would break and directly move to next activity. During this thing happens, it would just freeze the screen. Any other option to implement a tween animation to be executed for a fixed amount of time and later do some other task on completion of the animation. I choose this technique over frame-by-frame animation as frame-by-frame animation would need separate .png or .9.png for each of them hence increasing the .apk file size which I would like to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

1，Did you check the value of animationRotateCenter.getDuration()?
2,I think you should not use android:repeatCount="infinite"。
Hope that help you.